# Problem related to a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem:

[image]

I see that $\color{green}{|P(0)| \leq C}$ and so option 4 can be eliminated. If I take $\color {red}{P(x)=1+x^2 }\,\,\text{and} \,\,\color {blue}{C=1 >0}$,then also the given relation is satisfied and hence option 1 can not be right. From the given options, 2 appears to be correct choice but I do not know how to show it.

Can someone explain? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: Suppose the degree is $d$. Show that for large $x$, you have $\lvert P(x)\rvert \geqslant c\cdot \lvert x\rvert^d$ for some $c > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The growth of a polynomial for large $\lvert x\rvert$ is determined by its degree and the lead coefficient. Suppose

$$P(x) = a_dx^d + a_{d-1}x^{d-1} + \dotsb = a_d x^d + \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} a_k x^k$$

with $a_d \neq 0$. For $\lvert x\rvert \geqslant 1$, we then have

$$\begin{align}
\lvert P(x)\rvert &\leqslant \lvert a_d\rvert\cdot\lvert x\rvert^d + \sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\lvert a_k\rvert\cdot\lvert x\rvert^k\\
&\leqslant \lvert a_d\rvert\cdot\lvert x\rvert^d + \left(\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\lvert a_k\rvert\right)\lvert x\rvert^{d-1}\\
&= \left(\lvert a_d\rvert + \frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert}\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\lvert a_k\rvert\right)\lvert x\rvert^d.
\end{align}$$

For $\lvert x\rvert \to\infty$, the second term in the parenthesis tends to $0$, so the growth becomes practically indistinguishable from the growth of the leading term. More precisely, for

$$\lvert x\rvert \geqslant \max \left\lbrace 1,\, \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{d-1} \lvert a_k\rvert}{\varepsilon\cdot \lvert a_d\rvert} \right\rbrace,$$

we have

$$(1-\varepsilon)\lvert a_d\rvert\cdot\lvert x\rvert^d \leqslant \lvert P(x)\rvert \leqslant (1+\varepsilon)\lvert a_d\rvert\cdot\lvert x\rvert^d,$$

where the lower bound follows analogously from $\lvert P(x)\rvert \geqslant \lvert a_d\rvert\cdot\lvert x\rvert^d - \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} \lvert a_k\rvert\cdot\lvert x\rvert^k$.

Thus $P$ satisfies a growth condition

$$\lvert P(x)\rvert \leqslant K\cdot \lvert x\rvert^m\quad \text{ for } \lvert x\rvert \geqslant R\tag{1}$$

for some $K > 0$ if and only if $m \geqslant \deg P$ and a growth condition

$$\lvert P(x)\rvert \geqslant k \cdot \lvert x\rvert^m\quad \text{ for } \lvert x\rvert \geqslant R$$

for some $k > 0$ if and only if $m \leqslant \deg P$.

For $\lvert x\rvert \geqslant 1$, we have $1 + \lvert x\rvert \leqslant 2\lvert x\rvert$, hence the given growth condition $\lvert P(x)\rvert \leqslant C(1+\lvert x\rvert)^{5/2}$ implies a growth condition of the form $(1)$,

$$\lvert P(x)\rvert \leqslant \left(C\cdot 2^{5/2}\right)\lvert x\rvert^{5/2}\quad \text{ for }\lvert x\rvert \geqslant 1.$$

Hence $\deg P \leqslant \frac52$. Since the degree of a polynomial is an integer $\ldots$